# In-App Billing - how to set up my app correctly in Market / Google Play?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I would like to make my app freeware, but if a user is willing to retrieve additional features, it should be possible to 'activate' them after in-app payment.

Should I set up my app as "FREE" (or can that cause trouble later as this setting can't be change anymore?) and which way would you recommend to go - should I retrieve the additional stuff from my own website, or does Google provide a way for it after payment was successful?

Basically the app will be (and stay) really useful (well I hope) in its free state already, I just want to kinda provide additional goodies for the few that would be ready to support and maybe want to get even more out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, set up your app as free.

What you're describing is the freemium model, where you give the app for free, and charge for advanced features:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium

A lot of Android apps are successfully monetizing using the freemium model. One example is Angry Birds Space, a top downloaded free app, which uses in-app billing to sell Mighty Eagles or remove ads.